# Cross session cache

Tags: php, zend-framework, caching

Is there any cross(-user)-session cache mechanism?

The problem is:

- I'm building a Magento module (Magento+Zend on Linux) which frequently triggers SOAP queries;
- Some of those queries are just to request the sessionID, so it could be saved with a timeout control (considering each sessionID lasts for one hour)
- Those sessionId's are related to server-to-server communication; There's no relation with the current user session (backup operation, for example). That said, I'm not concerned about one impersonate another;

**I've heard several bad things/posts about APC - so I'm putting it away.** Let me know if you have any good argument to let re-consider it as an option.

**MemCached looks a good alternative**, since it looks like there's some sort of lib already implemented inside Zend to deal with it.

Basically, I'm concerned about reducing this sessionId requests.

Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE**

The answer bellow didn't actually solved the problem but comments did it. Zend_Cache (as mentioned by @Rijndael) is the solution to my situation.  The final code should be very similar to this:

```
$frontendOptions = array(
   'lifetime' => 7200, // cache lifetime of 2 hours
   'automatic_serialization' => true
);

$backendOptions = array(
    'cache_dir' => './tmp/' // Directory where to put the cache files
);

// getting a Zend_Cache_Core object
$cache = Zend_Cache::factory('Core',
                             'File',
                             $frontendOptions,
                             $backendOptions);

if( ($result = $cache->load('myresult')) === false ) {

    // cache miss; connect to the database 
    $db = Zend_Db::factory( [...] );
    $result = $db->fetchAll('SELECT * FROM huge_table');
    $cache->save($result, 'myresult');
} else {
    // cache hit! shout so that we know
    echo "This one is from cache!\n\n";
}
print_r($result);
```

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.cache.introduction.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the specifics of magento but as a ZF developer there are several ways you can approach this:

If by cross-session you are referring to an application that exists on the same server but under a different subdomain, you could do something like:

In application.ini:

```
session.domaincookie = .mysite.co.uk ;
```

Then in bootstrap,

```
Zend_Session::setOptions($this->getOption('session'));
```

The above approach will make session data visible across ALL subdomains.

If it is a 3rd party API then just store the sessionId in the local session:

```
$s = new Zend_Session_Namespace("user_session");
$s->session_id = $api->session_id;
$s->setExpirationSeconds(strtotime("+1 hour"));
```

Don't use APC, it is a deserted project. If you need memory caching, using Redis or Memcached. You can also use Zend_Cache.

Comment: by cross-session I meant cross(-user)-session. The whole app is going to run in the same server

Comment: Cross-user-session ? Same URI and user ? Whats the exact setup ?

Comment: if during the one user session I need to request a sessionId to a given server, why would I request another requestId to another user targeting the same server? Zend_Session_Namespace is not visible to all users, it's an info visible only to one user. Right?

Comment: Session IDs are unique per user. You cannot have 2 users with the same session IDs. Let me put it to you like this, IF I stole your session ID I would be able to impersonate you, not a good idea is it ?

Comment: Got your point, but in my case the sesssionId is not related to the user. It's a sort of 'conversation' between servers. There's no way one can impersonate another. I'm trying to avoid the server request twice the sessionID to execute operations another user is executing simultaneously. Imagine one server executing methods against another  (through soap) in order to backup data. It's not related to the current user itself, but instead a task that should be executed anyway.

Comment: I see. If you are reusing the session IDs then your best bet is to simply cache them. You can cache the IDs with Zend_Cache. You can use memcached backend for zend_cache if you like. see: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.cache.introduction.html

Comment: Great! I'll take a look into your tip. +1 for your extended attention.  I'll post the progress